# Iterative Hash Set up

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hashtable

I have the following array...

```
my @array=("100  2", "300  1", "200  3");
```

From this array I want to iteratively construct a hash.

Current Script:

```
my %hash; 
foreach (@array) {
 my @split = (split /\s+/, $_);
 %hash = ("$split[0]", "$split[1]");
}
```

Current Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
         '200' => '3'
        };
```

This is not what I want. My goal is...

Goal Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
         '100' => '2'
         '300' => '1'
         '200' => '3'
        };
```

What do I need to do?

I am using: Perl 5, Version 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to a hash—something you are doing each pass of the loop—replaces its contents. Replace

```
%hash = ("$split[0]", "$split[1]");
```

with

```
$hash{$split[0]} = $split[1];
```

---

Alternatively, replace everything with

```
my %hash = map { split } @array;
```

Comment: I used the Alternatively option, it works perfectly! @ikegami